# Files needed to include when using liblzf

Tags: c++, include, lzf

i want to use [liblzf](http://oldhome.schmorp.de/marc/liblzf.html) in my application that is written in c++

The description on the site says that It only uses 2 .c and 2 .h files but the tar.gz file contains 3 .h and 3 .c files. Can anyone tell me what should I only include in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lzf_c.c for compression, lzf_d.c for decompression. You don't need lzf.c which seems to be a testing harness. I suspect you have some tweaking to do to get it working with C++.

Comment: Thanks I got it working now. I just needed to comment out a single line to make it compile.